# Wrap text in a circle with angular and limit the string length

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm quite new to angular and I'm trying to get the text from the input field to wrap in the circular div so that the text does not go outside the border. Any help would be greatly appreciated here is my code - thanks!

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
    Add Information <textarea ng-model ="input" maxlength = "120" class = "textinput" </textarea>     

     <div class="textcircle">
        <span id="text">{{input}}</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .textinput{
    height: 15%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.textcircle{
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid #888080;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Museo-Sans;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#text{
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

UPDATE - I have changed the HTML/CSS and gotten the text to wrap well around the circle, but if a word is too long it moves outside the circle. Is there a way to limit the length of a word inside the div?

See an example with this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gj7tL/16/

Comment: Not sure why but all your text goes on one line. And one line only, are you aware of this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work!
http://jsfiddle.net/D2TL3/
Basically needed to change `<span>` to a `<div>` for text wrapping purposes.  Created an inner circle for `#text` to wrap with.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with angular itself, it can be done by css:

```
.textcircle{
        width:200px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 1000px;
        border: 1px solid #888080;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: Museo-Sans;
        font-weight: 300;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

I´ve just added the "overflow: hidden" in your css class.
http://jsfiddle.net/gztR6/

Comment: but overflow hidden doesnt show the content which goes beyond the circle..... the text should go down when touched borders of the circle.. :D

Comment: Oh yes, that kind of "collision detection" will be extremely hard to do. I think you can use a "hack" to make it work, but for it you'll need to use a font where all the characters use the same amount of space, and have a circle with a predefined width/height. Only then you could calculate the number of "lines" inside your circle along with the max number of letters in each of them, create one angular variable for each of them and then break the main string into these lines while the user inputs it...

Answer (score 0):

Not really an angular question (as that part seems to be working fine), more about CSS.

try this:

```
#text {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 30px
}
```

Filling text in a circular area with CSS is definitely an inexact science.